# How to deploy a portable gcc with cloog?

Tags: linux, gcc, mpfr

I'm trying to build a portable  version of gcc 4.8.2. (for only C/C++ languages)  The end result is have gcc installed into a specific application directory, eg, /opt/gcc-4.8.2 so that I can copy that directory from one computer to another (all computers are either intel corei5 or corei7, running recent Linux versions, eg, Ubuntu 12, Suse 10/11, Centos 5 & 6).

So far I'm able to build gcc ok, using --prefix to have the gcc outputs placed in a single directory (which can then be later copied to the other hosts). I configured & built gcc's dependencies (gmp, mpfr, mpc, isl) to have --disable-shared, so I can be sure that the final gcc, when copied to other hosts, won't complain about missing libraries or symbols.

I have a question with cloog.  I configured gcc with --with-cloog (to pick up my locally built cloog, which I built along with the other gcc dependencies). However, what I don't know, is whether I also need to copy the cloog libraries and binary to each host I copy gcc to?

Also, how can I test gcc & cloog interaction?  Is there a simple C file example and/or gcc command line that can be used to test whether gcc is successfully making use of cloog?

Additionally, are there any other considerations when trying to build a gcc which I then want to run on other hosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if *cloog* is installed as a shared library `libcloog-isl.so.*` or as a static one `libcloog.a` ; use

```
ldd $(gcc-4.8 -print-file-name=cc1)
```

to find out. Of course you need to install all the shared libraries dependencies. If `libcloog*so` appears in the output of above `ldd` command, it is a shared library. Otherwise a static one.

You could set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or add the directory containing `libcloog-isl.so.*` (e.g. `/usr/local/lib/` or `/opt/lib/` etc...) to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (then run `ldconfig`)

I am not entirely sure your `gcc` build can run on every platform you mentioned. There might be `libc*` dependencies. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20804529/841108). And perhaps also `binutils` dependencies (notably for `gcc-4.8 -flto` compilations).

To test `gcc` just compile *with optimizations* (e.g. `gcc-4.8 -Wall -O3`)  some non-trivial file.

Comment: "I am not entirely sure your gcc build can run on every platform you mentioned. There might be libc* dependencies."  .. yep, I was wondering about this too.  I hope to avoid that problem by performing the build of gcc on the oldest OS in our system, eg, Suse 10.